# Unity3d Sprite Mask Nonexistent in Build

Tags: unity, sprites, debugging, build-process

I am developing a 2D game which uses sprite masks to limit the player's information to a circle around them. The feature works perfectly in the Unity Editor. It can be disabled and reenabled, have the shape of the mask itself change, and more.

However, whenever I build the project and run the executible the screen is blank. If I disable the sprite masks altogether, the sprites are all visible. I have debugged Unity3d builds before, but that was specifically looking at variables as they changed during the execution of the program.

Does anyone have any specific knowledge related to sprite masks or have any idea why this would occur? I can provide more information if necessary. My current thought is that the sprite mask is masking everything for some reason. It's weird to me though that it would only break in the build.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. I would say that you are using the wrong pixel format for the masks, but then there is the fact that they work in editor. Can you test the build in another machine or device?

Comment: Yes we have tested it across the entire team on multiple devices. We have also isolated it to the sprite masks as any form of sprite masks results in a completely blank screen. If we have sprite masks enabled, but have nothing set on our platforms that indicates they should be hidden by sprite masks, then the screen is still blank.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before. It seemed to be related to the mask custom range. For example if my target order in layer is 99, then I have to set the range as [98,100]alt text

[image]

If I set the range as [98,99], the editor works fine, but the build shows no effect.

Here's a [link to the Unity forum post where I posted this in reply to a similar problem](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1513597/sprites-mask-with-custom-range-not-working-after-b.html?childToView=1811999#answer-1811999).

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thank you for contributing. [Links can be helpful, but they should not be the only piece of information in your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228147). In the future please include at least a summary of the relevant information from your linked source.